# Ajax not working es expected (Returns 0)

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, actions

I'm trying to "POST" data from my Form through ajax to a mysql database.
This code is hooked to the "after_setup_theme" action:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_anmeldung", "ajax_anmeldung");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_anmeldung", "ajax_anmeldung"); 

function ajax_anmeldung() {
    echo "<script>
        alert('hey');
        </script>";
    die();
}
```

And this is the JS code that calls it:

```
$('#teilnahme_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    jQuery.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: window.ajaxurl,
       data: {
           action: "ajax_anmeldung",
           name : name
       },
       success:function(data){
           alert(data);
       }
     });
});
```

When I run this I get returned a "0", nothing more.

When I tried: http://my-domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_anmeldung
I also get a "0".

I read all the others post on here surrounding this topic, but nothing seemed to help me, or I overlooked something really important.

Cheers

Comment: You don't need to echo hey on your script tag, only echo 'hey';

Comment: Thanks, but still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Add the following in your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'tnc_aj_scripts' );

function tnc_aj_scripts() {
   wp_register_script( "ajax_anmeldung_script", get_template_directory_uri(). '/my-ajax.js', array('jquery'),  '1.0', true);
   wp_localize_script( 'ajax_anmeldung_script', 'mYAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_anmeldung_script' );
}

add_action("wp_ajax_ajax_anmeldung", "ajax_anmeldung");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_anmeldung", "ajax_anmeldung");

function ajax_anmeldung() {
    $result['one'] = 'Hey';
    $result = json_encode($result);
    echo $result;
    die();
}
```

Create a .js file in your theme directory called my-ajax.js and put the following inside that file:

```
jQuery('#teilnahme_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    jQuery.ajax({
      type:"post",
      dataType : "json",
      url : mYAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: "ajax_anmeldung",
        name : name
      },
      success:function(data){
        alert(data.one);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I get "undefined" as a response. That probably means my code isn't executed, no?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line initially, Edited answer now, please try if it works.

Comment: Still undefined. I think my actions don't work. Im declare them in the functions.php file. Is that not correct?

Comment: Probably you're doing something wrong somewhere. Updated answer again with full code. Please try this

Answer (score 0):

When using "POST" as request type, exclude "action" in data param and append it to the url.

```
$('#teilnahme_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    jQuery.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: window.ajaxurl + '?action=ajax_anmeldung',
       data: {
         name : name
       },
       success:function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me. I also tried to combine your @Abdul Awals answer, which didn't work either. I still get "0" or "undefined" when it's combined.

Comment: Oh I see why it didn't work. Remove `e.preventDefault();` and see what happens -:

Comment: Still nothing, sadly.